# How to make Boolean write True or False in Ada

Tags: boolean, ada

I'm very new to programming and have just gotten started with Records and boolean in Ada.
I'm trying to make it so that whenever I write 'T' it will say "True" and whenever I write 'F' it will say False, but I´m not sure how to do that. In this assignment I'm not allowed to change `T: Boolean:= False;` this has to be in the code, but I´m not sure what I have to do to get what I want. I guess I have to do some sort of if statement like
But i´m not sure how to do that.
My code looks like the following:

```
type Sub_J is 
  record
 
     Y: Character:= '9';
     Q: Character:= 'p';
 
  end record; 

type Sub_B is
  record
     Y: Character:= 'J';
     Q: Character:= 'o';
  end record;

type Sub_O is 
  record
 
     T: Boolean:= False;
     L: Character:= '5';
 
  end record;

type DS3 is 
  record
 
     J: Sub_J;
     B: Sub_B;
     O: Sub_O;
 
  end record;

procedure Get_3(DSThree: out DS3) is
  
   Space: Character;            
  
begin 
  
   Put("Mata in datamängd: ");              
   Get(DSThree.J.Y);
   Get(Space);
   Get(DSThree.J.Q);
   Get(Space);
   Get(DSThree.B.Y);
   Get(Space);
   Get(DSThree.B.Q);
   Get(Space);              
   Get(DSThree.O.T);      
   Get(Space);
   Get(DSThree.O.L);
  
end Get_3;

procedure Put_3(DSThree: in DS3) is
    
begin 
  
   Put("Inmatad datamängd: ");
   Put(DSThree.J.Y);
   Put(" ");
   Put(DSThree.J.Q);
   Put(" ");
   Put(DSThree.B.Y);
   Put(" ");
   Put(DSThree.B.Q);
   Put(" ");                 
   Put(DSThree.O.T);
   Put(" ");
   Put(DSThree.O.L);           
  
end Put_3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you’re using `Ada.Text_IO.Put` (or `Put_Line`): what you have to do is to print the *image* of the variable.

In the case of a `Character` or `String`, the image is the thing itself. In the case of other simple types, you can apply the [attribute `Image`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-K-2.html#p88):

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put (T’Image);
```

This will result in `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unfortunately not very clear. You show a program, but the program is incomplete and not compilable, and you do not say explicitly which part of the program your question concerns -- is it about an input operation (Get), an output operation (Put), or something else?

You say your goal is "whenever I write 'T' it will say "True"", and likewise F for False. But do you mean that you write 'T' into the program's source code, or in response to an input operation (Get) when you run the program? And is it an output operation that you want to "say "True""? Or do you want to make 'T' and 'F' be abbreviations for True and False in the Ada source code?

If you want to be able to enter 'T' in response to a Get operation for a Boolean variable, for example B : Boolean, and have 'T' mean True, one way is to Get a Character value, for example Get(C) where C is a Character variable, and then make a case selection:

```
case C is
when 'T' => B := True;
when 'F' => B := False;
when others =>
   -- Erroneous input.
   -- Perhaps tell the user and ask for new input.
   ...
end case;
```

Note, however, that Get for a Character really does give the next character, and does not skip blank characters in the way Get for other types does. However it does skip line terminators (and page terminators).

Giving you a good answer would be much easier if you could show a compilable program and explain what you want it do.

Comment: Yes I realized that, but I wasnt even sure what I was asking. I'll do better posts in the futur. thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
procedure Get_3(DSThree: out DS3) is
  
  Space: Character;  
  True_Or_False: Character; 
   
begin 

  Put("Mata in datamängd: ");               
  Get(DSThree.J.Y);
  Get(Space);            
  Get(DSThree.J.Q);
  Get(Space);           
  Get(DSThree.B.Y);
  Get(Space);            
  Get(DSThree.B.Q);
  Get(Space);
  
  
  Get(True_Or_False);
  if True_Or_False = 'T' then
     DSThree.O.T:= True;
 
  elsif True_Or_False = 'F' then
     DSThree.O.T:= False;
  end if; 
  
  
  Get(Space);
  Get(DSThree.O.L);
  
end Get_3;

procedure Put_3(DSThree: in DS3) is
  
begin 
  
  Put("Inmatad datamängd: ");
  Put(DSThree.J.Y);
  Put(" ");            
  Put(DSThree.J.Q);
  Put(" ");            
  Put(DSThree.B.Y);
  Put(" ");     
  Put(DSThree.B.Q);
  Put(" ");
  
  
  if DSThree.O.T = True then
     Put("True");
 
  elsif DSThree.O.T = False then 
     Put("False");    
  end if;
  
  
  Put(" ");
  Put(DSThree.O.L);   
  
end Put_3;
```

Comment: You need **4** spaces to get code markup. And, don’t use tabs.

Comment: Good that you solved it. I have a couple of comments on your solution. First, consider what happens if the user, in response to Get(True_Or_False), enters some character that is neither 'T' nor 'F'. Then the code assigns no value to DSThree.O.T, so the default value remains. Is this your intent? Second, to test if a Boolean variable is True, there is a shorter way: instead of writing "if DSThree.O.T = True then", just write "if DSThree.O.T then". Instead of "if DSThree.O.T = False then", write "if not DSThree.O.T then". In fact your "elsif" test for False is unnecessary, an "else" is enough.